# MapBox zoom level not honored

Tags: objective-c, tiles, mapbox

I've built a control using the RMMapView.
I've also downloaded a map from MapBox to be offline available, and set the minimum and maximum zoom levels accordingly, like this:

> ```
> RMMapboxSource * tileSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:DEBUG_MAP_ID];
> RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:tileSource];
> mapView.minZoom = [[[tileSource infoDictionary]objectForKey:@"minzoom"] intValue];
> mapView.maxZoom = [[[tileSource infoDictionary]objectForKey:@"maxzoom"] intValue];
> [mapView setZoom:mapView.minZoom animated:YES];
> mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
> mapView.adjustTilesForRetinaDisplay = YES;
> [mapView setHideAttribution:YES];
> [self.view addSubview:mapView];
> ```

All good, but once I start zooming out, it seems like the min-zoom level is not honoured, no matter what I set it to, and the map disappears because it doesn't have tiles for that level.

Is there anything I'm missing here? The values in the dictionary are good, the zoom levels are set correctly. This applies to both the min-and max zoom, neither of them seem to have effect.

(On a quick side-note, I could not find a developer forum for MapBox. They do have a support-page, but it comes down to FAQ, e-mail us or pay for support. Is the best go-to place for these issues StackOverflow?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered you on support email, but try changing the `mapView` properties *after* you've added it to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Answer questions via email does not help anyone else, this being a site for helping more than just the OP.

Comment: Why does [initWithFrame: andTilesource:
    centerCoordinate: zoomLevel: maxZoomLevel: minZoomLevel: backgroundImage:] exist if the zoomLevel values are not honored?
Why are the setMaxZoom: & setMinZoom: values ignored if called on the object before it's been added to a superview?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could answer your zooming question, but to answer part 2, this seems like the only forum for mapbox right now.  I too am brand new to it and having a hard time finding answers

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I figured. I did see some of my questions in Google Cache, but they redirect to MapBox support. I figured they used to have sort of a message board.

I'll start asking them for support through e-mail then.