# How to set zoom level to (>18) in mapbox android?

Tags: android, zooming, mapbox

I am using mapbox to show the maps.
In the mapbox documentation, it is said to be maximum zoom level is 18. But my requirement is too zoom the map > 18.

I am using below library in the build.gradle

```
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:3.2.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Can you please help me out from this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

This will be coming in the 4.0.0 release of the Mapbox Android SDK (and should be in the [current snapshot releases](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#gradle)), see [this Github ticket](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/3712) for the implementation.

Once supported, you'll get/set the maximum zoom using:

```
map.getMaxZoom();
map.setMaxZoom(double);
```

The default will be 20 and the absolute maximum zoom will be 25 in v4.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @friedbunny. If I use zoom controls in the mapview, will zoom >18 ?

Comment: Yes, the default maximum zoom will be 20 in v4.0.0.

Comment: Yes that was understood in your previous answer. any other methods to zoom >18. Means any reflection method to set the MAXIMUM_SIZE ?

Comment: found this to be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22082182/2162226 , solution found: `mMapboxMap.setMaxZoomPreference(25.5);`

Comment: Still working in v9